# Can a const variable be assigned in parameters with a default value (as an optional parameter)?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I need to add optional parameters to the end of most function calls in my program. Right now the function's parameters look along the lines of

```
foo(int a, char b, const unique_ptr c)
```

What I've added is a default value for the last parameter to make it optional so it looks like

```
foo(int a, char b, const unique_ptr c = NULL)
```

Can a const variable be assigned in the parameters as I've done? Or does this go against the nature of constant variables?

Comment: What does your compiler tell you?

Comment: That `const` for parameter is not part of signature of the function.

Comment: That `const` only protects you to write it inside the function definition.

Comment: It spits out hundreds of errors about type mismatches along with other assorted errors. The one that confuses me specifically is no known conversion of  `'std::unique_ptr<opentracing::v2::Span>' to 'const opentracing::v2::Span*'`  even though I would think both would be the same.

Comment: `unique_ptr` requires a template argument list and a correct initialization, `const` is irrelevant here, also it is initialization rather that assignment that is performed for defaulted function parameters (don't let presence of `=` confuse you)

Comment: @GabrielKay These are two different types. You cannot implicitly convert a `std::unique_ptr` to a pointer.

Comment: Using a `unique_ptr` as a parameter means you are transferring sole ownership of the passed argument to the foo function.  Is passing ownership intended?

Comment: @Eljay I am fine passing sole ownership, do you know of a way to convert a unique_ptr to a raw pointer? I think that's what my compiler may have been complaining about?

Comment: @GabrielKay Use `std::unique_ptr::get()` or dereference it with `*`, see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables that are qualified as `const` can be initialized, but not altered (e.g. assigned to) afterwards. This is true for any ordinary variable as well as a function parameter. Lets simplify your example to

```
void foo(const int a = 1) {}
```

This in itself is a valid function signature, it tells the compiler that the parameter `a` is not modified within the function body. This will hence not compile:

```
void illegalFoo(const int a = 1) { a = 2; /* Error, won't compile */ }
```

If the calling code passes a value to the function

```
foo(3);
```

the function parameter `a` is initialized to `3` in this example, but again, not changed in the function body. The same reasoning is true for a `std::unique_ptr` argument:

```
void foo(const std::unique_ptr<SomeClass> ptr = nullptr)
{
    /* No way to alter ptr here */
}
```

Note, however, that this function signature makes little sense. Passing `std::unique_ptr` by value means transferring ownership, but a const-qualified instance cannot be cast to an rvalue-reference for the sake of move-constructing another owning smart pointer from it. If no ownership semantics shall be associated with such a function, pass a raw pointer - it can equally well be declared const and defaulted to `nullptr`.

Comment: `const` variables cannot be assigned at all, this is initialization.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is **overload** your function, instead of adding a default value for the parameter within its original definition. Overloading a function looks like this:

```
void foo(int a, int b) {
    // this is the original definition, takes 2 parameters, so we initialize c to 0:
    const int c = 0;
    return a + b;
}
// then, right underneath, you add an overloaded definition for the function:
void foo(int a, int b, const int c) {
    // this is the overloaded definition, takes 3 parameters
    return a + b + c;
}
```

This way, the parameter `c` is entirely optional, when you call `foo()`.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with what you've done.

Bear in mind that this syntax:

```
foo(int a, char b, const unique_ptr c = NULL);
```

Is basically just syntactical sugar for this:

```
foo(int a, char b, const unique_ptr c);
foo(int a, char b) {
    foo(a, b, NULL);
}
```

Which is obviously valid and legal, with the proviso that, while it's technically allowed to assign `nullptr` or `NULL` to a `std::unique_ptr`, this is probably bad practice since you're not otherwise allowed to assign raw pointers directly to a smart pointer (i.e. `std::unique_ptr<int> ptr = new int(5);` will not compile).

It's probably better to write it like this:

```
foo(int a, char b, const unique_ptr c = {});
```